# Firefox Addon content script for a site like in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Can somebody provide an example of content script which executes only on example.com pages? Just like in Chrome extensions.

I can't figure out with this SDKs and weird things. In Chrome it's easy.

Please, no Firefox XUL interface.

I mean, it will be very good to see whole extension example, not just code.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)

Comment: Yes, but it will be a great help to have a sample extension. Because other parts of documentation are very... I just can't understand where I need to put this all and it will be cool to understood on practice, not theory.

Comment: There's a simple example on the page I linked

Comment: Um... there is a code, but not example extension.

Comment: Here is a sample extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29 - however when it tells you to paste in - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29#Implementing_the_add-on - instead paste in what is on the pageMod docs. Then after pasting get back to the getting started docs, it tells you how to run it in firefox (with jpm run) and create an xpi for upload (jpm xpi). You might have to enable developer prefs in your profiles or use jpm sign before dragging and dropping the xpi into firefox -

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/18/signing-firefox-add-ons-with-jpm-sign/